# Choose a local file w/o uploading the chosen file

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I am making a simple development tool for myself using PHP on my local development server.

I would like a way to have a simple file-chooser to select a file without uploading it, but just retaining the file path. This is useful, because I will be the only one using the tool, and so PHP will have access to the chosen file without having it uploaded.

My first thought is to have a `<input type="file"...>`, but as far as I know, there's no way to prevent the upload from happening.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: PHP is server-side, how would it have access to the file without uploading it?

Comment: are you trying to get the local path to the file? you could read out the filename using javascript but not the filepath.

Comment: @Kau-Boy: Yeah, I need the local path. @Nick: It's my local dev server, thus server=local

Comment: Than I'm afraid it is not possible as the local path should never be read client or server side because of security reasons.

Comment: @Austin: If that's the case, is this the appropriate technology to use?

Comment: @Kau-Boy: When you upload a file, the path goes with it, that's the default behavior (depending on browser!), open firebug or the chrome console and look at the POST to see this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this will only ever be run locally, you could write a PHP-based file chooser/locator. You would have complete control over behavior and presentation this way.

Answer (score 1):

Ill do something like the same input type file.

The form will not be a multipart one, a normal form with a onSubmit event, that take the value of the file input and will assign that value to a hidden input that is taken in the action of that form...

Answer (score 1):

Though you can get the file name of a file entered in an `<input type="file" …>` field using JavaScript (and send this name to the server, e.g. using `XMLHttpRequest`), you can't get the full path, as this would create a huge security implication.

Example (you don't have to use a `<form>` for this):

```
<input type="file" id="fileField">
<input type="button" value="Click here!" onclick="getFileName()">

<script>
function getFileName() {
  var fileEl = document.getElementById("fileField");
  console.log(fileEl.value);
  // other stuff, e.g. send fileEl.value using XMLHttpRequest
}
</script>
```